# return variable from a nested callback in node.js

Tags: node.js, callback

I have the results of my query in `result` but I can not pass it to browser, it is showing empty.
how can I return the `result` to `res.send('result')`?

```
myApp.get('/agg',function(req,res){
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    // Execute aggregate, notice the pipeline is expressed as an Array
    db.collection('projects').aggregate([{$match:{school_state:"DC"}}, {$group:{_id: "$primary_focus_subject",total_amount:{$sum: "$total_donations"}}}],function(err,result){
    console.log(result);

    db.close();
    });
});

res.send(result);
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 solutions :

- put `res.send(result);` where you have `console.log(result)`
- having a promise wrapping your MongoClient.connect like this :

  ```
  let promise = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    MongoClient.connect(url,function(err,db){
      db.collection('projects').aggregate([{$match:{school_state:"DC"}}, {$group:{_id: "$primary_focus_subject",total_amount:{$sum: "$total_donations"}}}],function(err,result){
        if(err) reject(err)
        resolve(result);
      });
    });    
  })
  ```