# In the browser showing empty while fetching data from mongodb and send to my getdata.ejs file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

My index.js file get method

```
app.get('/getdata', function(req, res){
  var resultArray = [];
  mongo.connect(url, function(err, db){
    assert.equal(null, err);
    var cursor = db.collection('satyamsoft').find();
    cursor.forEach(function(doc, err){
      assert.equal(null, err);
      resultArray.push(doc);
      console.log(resultArray);
    });

  });

  res.render('pages/getdata', {holedata: resultArray});
});
```

My getdata.ejs file

```html
<h2> Family Details </h2>
<ul>
    <% holedata.forEach(function(data) { %>
        <li><%= data.name %> - <%= data.title %> - <%= data.age %></li>
    <% }); %>
</ul>
```

After executing the get method in the console showing data which is fetch from mongodb[Colnose data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PT8Ml.png)

But in the web page showing empty [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cn7Ht.png)

Am i doing anything wrong. Please help me. Advance thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This might help on client side in your **.ejs** file -

```
<script>
  var holedata = <%- JSON.stringify(holedata) %>;
</script>
```

Comment: the problem isn't here : he returns his value before it's set (thanks javascript asynchronicity) the solution is more like this : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43697903/return-variable-from-a-nested-callback-in-node-js/43698017#43698017

Comment: I got output when I put res.render() function inside the forEach function. But in the webpage its returning only first record. From the second record console showing error like **Can't send headers after they are sent** @mJehanno

Comment: i guess that you tried the first solution (having `res.render` in the mongo connect) you should use the promise-based solutions i think you wouldn't have this problem ...or tired to put `res.render` right after the `foreach`